# Setting the default application in IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7

How do you the default application in IIS 7?
I have the default web site node with several applications underneath it.
Each application has its default document loaded and if I point my browser to

http://server/appName

It works fine, it resolves to that apps default document set in the IIS settings.

How can I set it so that if I go to

http://server

It will automatically go to http://server/appName

A caveat is that the default web site's root is c:\inetpub\wwwroot where as my applications are located in c:\websites\app1,app2,etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just put an `index.html` file in there with a meta redirect in it.

Comment: This answer would have been a lot more helpful with a complete explanation or link to a complete explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I asked the same question [on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/411184/how-to-change-default-application-in-a-website-in-iis-7-5-on-windows-7), and figured out that you can change the physical path of the default web site (see [my answer](https://serverfault.com/a/411210/66848)).